# Why two divs are not side by side

Tags: html, css

I would like a wide top image, then two divs below side by side. One containing header and paragraph and one an image:

I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <img class="full-width-image" src="img/location/1.gif">
    <div id = "left">
        <h1 class = "top-padded">The Progs</h1>
        <p>wdnweidnweldnwnwlenwwnww</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "right">
        <img class="half-width-image" src="img/location/1.gif">
    </div>
</body>
```

And this:

```
#left {float: left;}

#right {float: right;}

.top-padded {padding-top: 1%;}

.full-width-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.half-width-image {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}
```

But they are still stacked on top of each other? I though float left and right was supposed to achieve this effect?

Comment: Remove `float:right;` from `#right`. Also add `display:inline-block;` to both `#left` &  `#right`

Comment: If i understood correctly, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aw4mhjkb/) what you want right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the widths of the containers. Please try the following code:

```
#left {float: left; width: 69%;}

#right {float: left; width: 30%;}

.top-padded {
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.full-width-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }

.half-width-image {
    height: auto;
}
```

Setting the float to left of the right div should also work.

Anyway, I would recommend to make the width of the right div static like:

```
#right {float: right; width: 300px;}
```